Flask + Waitress - Is my API limited to the number of workers when I spawn new threads inside endpoints?
By default the application served with waitress uses 4 threads. The statemnt below is from waitress documentation:

threads:
The number of threads used to process application logic (integer).
Default: 4

Let's imagine I spawn a new thread in one of my endpoints with code like this (this is only an example, not in 'good-practices' manner):
import threading

@app.route(/some/route, methods=["GET"])
def handle():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=some_function)
    thread.start()
    return "a background task has started..."

What is the relationship between the 4 workers the server uses and threads created this way? If 100 requests are sent then 100 threads will be created. How it realtes to the 4 workers? Will the 100 threads be queued somehow? This is not clear to me and I don't know how it affects the performance and machine resources - for example if I change the server workers to 2 will the execution of the 100 threads in the background be slower or no effect. I can't get it clearly for documentation

This is not how you do threading, if you're going to create a background function, just use Redis, and a listener script. Run both with supervisorctl, don't forget to log them.
Create a stack for new background process tasks, and you will have a queue for background processes. You can tackle this queue from the micro service, and you can use as many processes and threads as your server allows.
